# illegal blobKey error in unit test google app engine 1.6.4

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit

Strange thing happening here. When running any unit test that calls:

```
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);
writeChannel.closeFinally();
```

i get the following exception - the code runs fine outside the unit test and on other workstations - so it's an environment issue on a windows XP laptop i'm forced to use. Tests run fine on my other pcs and laptops (running ubuntu)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: illegal blobKey: pIONuF92LGIK8TV41YSSdQ
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.FileBlobStorage.getFileForBlob(FileBlobStorage.java:95)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.FileBlobStorage.storeBlob(FileBlobStorage.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.BlobstoreFile.getOutputStream(BlobstoreFile.java:225)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.FileMetadata.setFinalized(FileMetadata.java:97)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.BlobstoreFile.setFinalized(BlobstoreFile.java:212)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.LocalFileService.close(LocalFileService.java:334)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:498)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:452)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I just confirmed the difference between the workstation with the error . I was using google app engine 1.6.4 SDK - the others sill had 1.6.3.1. This is a bug on 1.6.4 i'll report.

Comment: bug reported:http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7291

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid this by adding a LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig() to your LocalServiceTestHelper setup. I just got it working after adding this to the test class that was failing.

I'm not sure if this is indeed a bug. I supose that the bug was before when the SDK was providing the local blobstore emulation without proper test setup configuration.